# Transaction scope for 3 location

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I have seen many transaction scope example and mostly only show 2 location examples. If I have 3 location how should I put scopes together. I am trying like below is this correct?  Another question I do not understand why must the second connectString2 be under the first connectString1?

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{  
 using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1)) 
 {     
   using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))    
   {    
   }    
   using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(connectString3))    
   {    
   }    
 }
}
```

Setting up individual transaction

```
            int backUpCentralCopy = 0, backUpCentral = 0;
            int rollbackBoolean = 0;


            MySqlTransaction transactionLocal = null;
            MySqlConnection connectionLocal = null;
            transactionConnectionLocal1 callTransactionConnectionLocal1 = null;
            try
            {
                callTransactionConnectionLocal1 = new transactionConnectionLocal1();
                connectionLocal = callTransactionConnectionLocal1.localConnection1;
                connectionLocal.Open();
                transactionLocal = connectionLocal.BeginTransaction();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Error From Database Connection (Local Server Is Down) " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
            {
                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From Database Connection (Local Server Is Down) " + ex.Message);
            }


            globalConnectionLocal1 myConnect1 = null;
            MySqlDataReader myReader1 = null;
            MySqlTransaction transactionCentralCopy = null;
            MySqlConnection connectionCentralCopy = null;
            transactionConnectionCentralCopy1 callTransactionConnectionCentralCopy1 = null;
            try
            {
                myConnect1 = new globalConnectionLocal1();
                myConnect1.command.CommandText = "Select  " +
                       "tblUpdateCentralCopy.updateCentralCopyID " +
                       "From tblUpdateCentralCopy ";
                myReader1 = myConnect1.command.ExecuteReader();

                if (myReader1.HasRows == true)
                {
                    backUpCentralCopy = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        callTransactionConnectionCentralCopy1 = new transactionConnectionCentralCopy1();
                        connectionCentralCopy = callTransactionConnectionCentralCopy1.centralCopyConnection1;
                        connectionCentralCopy.Open();
                        transactionCentralCopy = connectionCentralCopy.BeginTransaction();
                    }
                    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        rollbackBoolean = 1;
                        backUpCentralCopy = 1;
                        MessageBox.Show("Error From Database Connection (Central C Is Down) " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                    {
                        rollbackBoolean = 1;
                        backUpCentralCopy = 1;
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From Database Connection (Central C Is Down) " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                //backUpCentralCopy = 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Error From UCC Check " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
            {
                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                //backUpCentralCopy = 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From UCC Check " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                myReader1.Close();
                myConnect1.command.Dispose();
                myConnect1.connection1.Close();
            }
```

This section I am reading from data grid each value and doing the insert and update operation accordingly

```
for (int j = 0; j < gridTransfer.RowCount; j++)
 {

String mySelectQuery6 = "Select tblProduct.productTotalStock, " +
                                                "tblProduct.productTotalAmount, " +
                                                "tblProduct.productPrice " +
                                                "From tblProduct " +
                                                "Where tblProduct.productID=" + Convert.ToInt32(this.gridTransfer[0, j].Value.ToString());

                        MySqlDataReader myReader8 = null;

                        MySqlCommand myCommandLocal11 = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery6);
                        myCommandLocal11.Connection = connectionLocal;

                        int chTSICBefore = 0;
                        double chTAICBefore = 0.00, chACICBefore = 0.00;

                        try
                        {
                            myReader8 = myCommandLocal11.ExecuteReader();
                            while (myReader8.Read())
                            {
                                chTSICBefore = Convert.ToInt16(myReader8.GetValue(0).ToString());
                                chTAICBefore = Convert.ToDouble(myReader8.GetValue(1).ToString());
                                chACICBefore = Convert.ToDouble(myReader8.GetValue(2).ToString());
                            }
                            if (chTSICBefore <= 0 || chTAICBefore <= 0.00 || chACICBefore <= 0.00)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error From Before chTSICBefore = " + chTSICBefore + " And chACICBefore = " + chACICBefore + " And chACICBefore = " + chACICBefore + " For pID = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.gridTransfer[0, j].Value.ToString()));
                                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                        {
                            rollbackBoolean = 1;
                            MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandLocal11 mySelectQuery6 " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                        {
                            rollbackBoolean = 1;
                            MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandLocal11 mySelectQuery6 " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            myReader8.Close();
                            myCommandLocal11.Dispose();
                        }

                        if (chTSICBefore > 0 && chTAICBefore > 0.00 && chACICBefore > 0.00)
                        {
                            String myInsertQuery3 = "Insert into tblTransferDetails " +
                                             "Set transferDetailsID = " + transferDetailsID + ", " +
                                             "transferID=" + transferID + ", " +
                                             "outletID = " + globalSettings.settingOutletID + ", " +
                                             "stockID = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.gridTransfer[3, j].Value.ToString()) + ", " +
                                             "productID= " + Convert.ToInt32(this.gridTransfer[0, j].Value.ToString()) + ", " +
                                             "productType = '" + this.gridTransfer[2, j].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                                             "stockQuantity = 1, " +
                                             "stockSIQ = '" + this.gridTransfer[10, j].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                                             "costPrice = " + Convert.ToDouble(this.gridTransfer[12, j].Value.ToString()) + ", " +
                                             "transferPrice = " + Convert.ToDouble(this.gridTransfer[13, j].Value.ToString());

                            MySqlCommand myCommandLocal12 = new MySqlCommand(myInsertQuery3);

                            try
                            {
                                myCommandLocal12.Connection = connectionLocal;
                                myCommandLocal12.Transaction = transactionLocal;
                                myCommandLocal12.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                totalCost = totalCost + Convert.ToDouble(this.gridTransfer[12, j].Value.ToString());
                                totalTransferAmount = totalTransferAmount + Convert.ToDouble(this.gridTransfer[14, j].Value.ToString());

                            }
                            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                            {
                                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandLocal12 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                            }
                            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                            {
                                rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandLocal12 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                myCommandLocal12.Dispose();
                            }

                            if (backUpCentralCopy == 0)
                            {
                                MySqlCommand myCommandCentralCopy7 = new MySqlCommand(myInsertQuery3);
                                try
                                {
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Connection = connectionCentralCopy;
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Transaction = transactionCentralCopy;
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                }
                                catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandCentralCopy7 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandCentralCopy7 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String myInsertQueryReplace3 = myInsertQuery3.Replace("'", "''");
                                MySqlCommand myCommandCentralCopy7 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tblUpdateCentralCopy SET updateCentralCopyQuery='" + myInsertQueryReplace3 + "'");

                                try
                                {
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Connection = connectionLocal;
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Transaction = transactionLocal;
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandCentralCopy7 myInsertQueryReplace3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandCentralCopy7 myInsertQueryReplace3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    myCommandCentralCopy7.Dispose();
                                }
                            }

                            if (backUpCentral == 0)
                            {
                                MySqlCommand myCommandCentral4 = new MySqlCommand(myInsertQuery3);
                                try
                                {
                                    myCommandCentral4.Connection = connectionCentral;
                                    myCommandCentral4.Transaction = transactionCentral;
                                    myCommandCentral4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandCentral4 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandCentral4 myInsertQuery3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    myCommandCentral4.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String myInsertQueryReplace3 = myInsertQuery3.Replace("'", "''");
                                MySqlCommand myCommandCentral4 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tblUpdateCentral SET updateCentralQuery='" + myInsertQueryReplace3 + "'");

                                try
                                {
                                    //myCommandCentralDB3.CommandText = "Insert into tblUpdateCentral SET updateCentralQuery='" + myInsertQuery1 + "'";
                                    myCommandCentral4.Connection = connectionLocal;
                                    myCommandCentral4.Transaction = transactionLocal;
                                    myCommandCentral4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error From myCommandCentral4 myInsertQueryReplace3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                                {
                                    rollbackBoolean = 1;
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error Sockets From myCommandCentral4 myInsertQueryReplace3" + ex.Message);
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    myCommandCentral4.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

A`TransactionScope` is contextual to the currently executing thread until it is disposed. It should be in your outermost `using` statement (which you have correctly indicated).

Connections can be created/disposed anywhere on the current thread until the scope is disposed. This includes declarations in other methods or even other classes and assemblies.

Thus, you should wrap your connections with `using` in the places that you want to instantiate and dispose them. The purpose of the `using` block does not change just because you have it wrapped in a `TransactionScope`.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{  
   using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1)) 
   {
   }

   using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))    
   {    
   }

   using (SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(connectString3))    
   {    
   }

   scope.Complete(); // call this otherwise the transaction will be rolled back  
}
```

Note that you can also legally nest scopes (although that can quickly become confusing).

If you haven't already noticed, as soon as you create multiple connections within the same scope, the transaction will be automatically escalated to use the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC). The DTC is pretty easy to configure.

Multi-threaded transactions are also possible using [`DependentTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction.aspx).

Comment: thank you for the answer.I do not get you here "The purpose of the using block does not change just because you have it wrapped in a TransactionScope." Now my next problem currently I have a for loop which I read each row of a datagrid then I run different insert statement for each of the db. So in this transactioScope case I have to run one for loop(the original for loop) then maybe store the queries into a form of array then run two more loop for the other connection it that a good strategy?

Comment: 1) I mean that `using` doesn't function any differently if it's inside a transaction scope. 2) As long as you are inside the scope, you should be able to execute your commands in whatever order you want. However, it may be cleaner/faster to build a list of all your database operations first, and then execute them in a single block. If you need more help with that, please post some specific code.

Comment: I have added 2 section one section I show how I setup up individual transaction. Then another section I show a for loop and in that I run individual query according to different transactions. So if I need to move to transaction Scope what is the best method then.

Comment: A couple things I see in your code: 1) if you catch all your exceptions, then the transaction will commit. That's probably not what you want. 2) Mixing reads and writes within a transaction might be problematic (depending on what you are trying to accomplish). I think you should create all of the `INSERT/UPDATE` queries you want to run outside of the transaction scope, and then execute them inside the scope. If there is an exception, let it bubble up to the scope so that it can rollback the transaction (you can still catch it higher up).

Comment: actually my current method works but as you know .net connector for mysql does not support distributed transaction. So currently I will commit each individual transaction finally. The problem is have multiple insert/update query which is goes according to the data grid lines. When you say create outside means save them into an array is it?

Comment: what do you mean exactly to create all the insert/update outside the transaction scope any details on that? Thank you.